# Appium: Could not find a device to launch

Tags: python, ios, appium

i've updated Appium to run with Xcode 8.2 and now my tests fail to launch a simulator with the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a device to launch. 
You requested 'iPhone (10.2 Simulator)', but the available devices were: ["iPad Air (10.2) [4002EEFA-F56A-4A1E-850B-C3BF4FD773EA] (Simulator)","iPad Air 2 (10.2) .....
```

My Appium setup looks like this:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities={
            'app': app,
            'platformName': 'iOS',
            'deviceName': 'iPhone 7 plus',
            'platformVersion': '10.2'
        })
```

The error message displays a weird string for the device type: 'iPhone' instead of 'iPhone 7 plus".

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading from Appium 1.6.3 to 1.6 fixed the problem.